# How to make id with text auto increment in java?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to select data from mysql and input into JComboBox as an auto increment.

```
   DefaultComboBoxModel mo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
   try {
       rs = stmt.executeQuery("select pid from tbpatient");
       while(rs.next()) {
           mo.addElement(rs.getString(1));
       }
   } catch(SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   jComboBox1.setModel(mo);
```

}

But I want my text show "P001" and auto increment.

Comment: But "P001" isn't something that you can automatically add one to, from a DB perspective.  You'd have to let the 'P' portion represent a property, then pull the ID from the database.  Although, that raises another question - do other properties have an auto-update property?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is store the key as two columns. A char prefix and an auto-incrementing int, both of which are grouped for the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE myItems (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    prefix CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, prefix),
```